# How to get a console window from a C++/MFC program?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, console, console-application

I am working on an existing C++/MFC Windows program, and I would like to get the console for text output. I found no option for that.

Can I set an option to get a console window from a C++/MFC program without redoing the project from scratch?

Can I avoid using the AllocConsole() function call, and just set the project options?

In case I must use AllocConsole(), where can I call it? I have no main() function in the program, so I do not know which is the entry point.

Comment: If this is just for debugging, MFC programs do this using the TRACE macro. It sends to the output window in Visual C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use AllocConsole - either a windows program is console, or it's not. You can do so e.g. in CWinApp::InitInstance, since WinMain is abstracted away for you by MFC. But you can do it from anywhere really.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However for what I need, at this point it is quicker to just use a log file.

Comment: For 95% of the cases people ask this question for, it is, yes.